# Changing excel cell's formula based on another cell's value

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to adjust a cell's formula based on the value of another cell. If any cell in column T is equal to 0, then the formula will change for column P. I have created three different versions to solve this issue; however, they are all getting errors. I will post the code below and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

----------- Version 1 --------

```
Private Sub NameCheck1_Click()

    Dim a As Range
    With Worksheets(18).Range("T3367:T5000").Activate
    Set a = .Find(0, LookIn:=xlValues)
    
        If Not a Is Nothing Then
            
            ActiveCell("", "P").FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(RC[-13]="" - 0"","""",IF(RC[-13]="" - 0"","""",IF([@TM]="""","""",IF(RC[-1]=""not found"","""",XLOOKUP(RC[-1],TMs!C[-12],TMs!C[-12],""not found"",1)))))"
    
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---------- Version 2 ----------

```
Private Sub NameCheck2_Click()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim b As Long
    LastRow = Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For b = 3367 To LastRow
    
        If Range("T" & b).Value = 0 Then
            Range("P" & b).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-13]="" - 0"","""",IF(RC[-13]="" - 0"","""",IF([@TM]="""","""",IF(RC[-1]=""not found"","""",XLOOKUP(RC[-1],TMs!C[-12],TMs!C[-12],""not found"",1)))))"

        End If
    Next b
End Sub
```

---------  Version 3 ------------

```
Private Sub NameCheck3_Click()

    Dim c As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
    For c = 3367 To LastRow
    
        If Cells(c, 20).Value = 0 Then
            Range("P" & c).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-13]="" - 0"","""",IF(RC[-13]="" - 0"","""",IF([@TM]="""","""",IF(RC[-1]=""not found"","""",XLOOKUP(RC[-1],TMs!C[-12],TMs!C[-12],""not found"",1)))))"

        End If
    Next c   
End Sub
```

For versions two and three, I am getting run time error '13'. I also had this error for version 1, but I was able to get it out despite the code still won't work. Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you could state the error messages.

Comment: Errors provide Error Numbers and descriptions for a very good reason. Please post each error you receive

Comment: In v1 `With Worksheets(18).Range("T3367:T5000").Activate` is wrong, remove the '.activate`.

Comment: Have you tried testing the formula in a cell? To make sure the error is not occurring because of a typo in the formula

Comment: The formula I use has been tested, and I know it works. I believe I am getting the error somewhere in my if statement. @Maya